# How to find maximal sums in subarrays?

Tags: java, algorithm

Input: Size of array n, array of integers A[1..n]. -10^6 <= A[i] <= 10^6.

For all elements find a subarray with maximum sum that covers that element(more formally, for every i, find the largest value A[l] + A[l + 1] + · · · + A[r]
among all pairs of indices l and r such that 1 ≤ l ≤ i ≤ r ≤ n) . 
Output: n integers, where i-th of them should be equal to the maximal sum of subarray among all the cover the position i in A.
 Time limit - 3 seconds.

Example:
5

2 -3 -3 -3 2

Output: 2 -1 -3 -1 2

I've written an algorithm, but it's not fast enough. How to make it more efficient?

```java
public class MaximalSumSubarray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FastScanner in = new FastScanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);

        int q;
        q = in.nextInt();
        int[] t = new int[q];

        for (int i = 0; i < q; ++i) {
            t[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        long[] result = new long[q];

        ///
        long[] temp = new long[q+1];

        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < q; j++) {
                temp[j+1] += t[i];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            long max = -1000000;
            for (int l = 0; l <= i; l++) {
                for (int r = i; r < q; r++) {
                    if (temp[r+1] - temp[l] >= max) {
                        result[i] = temp[r+1] - temp[l];
                        max = result[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ////

        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i) {
            out.print(result[i] + " ");
        }

        out.close();
    }

    static class FastScanner {

        BufferedReader br;
        StringTokenizer st;

        FastScanner(InputStream stream) {
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        String next() {
            while (st == null || !st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                try {
                    st = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return st.nextToken();
        }

        int nextInt() {
            return Integer.parseInt(next());
        }
    }
}
```

- task is not from any competitions, it's a homework for coursera.

Comment: when q gets big you are in trouble because you are doing like 2*q^2 loops. see if you can check for max in your first q^2 loop.

Comment: @mavriksc thought about it, but couldn't find a way. any advices?

Comment: Starting from the beginning of the array, compute the best **forward** sum for each index `i`. If `bestForwardSum[i-1]` is negative, then `bestForwardSum[i] = t[i]`. Otherwise, `bestForwardSum[i] = bestForwardSum[i-1] + t[i]`. Then use a similar procedure to compute the best **backward** sum, starting from the end of the array. Given those two arrays (`bestForwardSum[]` and `bestBackwardSum[]`), the rest is easy.

Comment: In other words: Kadane's algorithm forward and backwards, clever.

Comment: @maraca: AFAICT, user3386109 is suggesting applying an O(n^2)-time summing approach twice, once in each direction; your suggestion of applying Kadane's O(n)-time algorithm in each direction is *better*.  (Kadane's algorithm computes the best backward sum for each index i starting from the beginning of the array, or each forward sum starting from the end.)